# how to configure postfix behind haproxy?

Tags: postfix, haproxy, hardening, vulnerability

During the last years I had an emailserver running for my small business without problems.

Now that my company has grown, I wanted to add a bit of redundancy and added a failover emailserver with a loadbalancer in front (haproxy).

All went fine until 1 week ago when we fell victim to spammers and i had to shut down everything. Using google a lot, I found out that a loadbalancer without the correct config converts my postfix into an open relay.

I would like to solve this and also found a lot of docs, but frankly now I'm a bit lost. I know that I have to add send-proxy in haproxy.cfg amongst other changes, but I just can't figure out how to add postscreen in order to harden postfix again.

Could anyone guide me or at least give me some link which I haven't found to a manual or tutorial of how this could be achieved?

I admit that I'm getting lost in the postfix official docs.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: the whole point of PROXY protocol is NOT to bother with messy stuff such as TPROXY

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this helps somebody out. The configuraton of haproxy I do differently because I'm running inside a kubernetes cluster. But the configuration of postfix, you update two files, accordingly

master.cf

```
# Exposed SMTP service (postscreen support is needed to support the proxy protocol [search postscreen_upstream_proxy_protocol in main.cf])
smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       1       postscreen
smtpd     pass  -       -       -       -       -       smtpd
```

main.cf

```
# This is required to support the proxy protocol to acquire the correct source ip address from whoever is connecting to this server
# It's really important to get this information because otherwise ALL your connections will come from your internal ip address
# Guess what you allow to send emails, without question? Thats right! You're $mynetworks. Which means because you cannot get the
# correct source ip address, it permits EVERYBODY TO SEND EMAIL THROUGH YOUR SERVER! You basically become an open relay
postscreen_upstream_proxy_protocol = haproxy
postscreen_upstream_proxy_timeout = 5s
```

Comment: Thomas thank you for the hint. will check it asap.

Answer (score 1):

**SMTP through HAProxy usint TProxy**

You would need to use [TProxy](https://www.haproxy.org/download/1.8/doc/configuration.txt) in order to preserve the IP address of the client. *search for tproxy*  This assumes the public IP is hitting haproxy.

**Or just use MX**

Another method would be to NAT port 25 from 2 public IP's and just use 2 MX records.  The MTA's will deal with load balancing as well.